# Perspective projection of a 3D model to a 2D plane

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to project a 3D model to a 2D plane and I found I should use the projection equation `C*((R*X)+T)` to do so. `C`, which is the camera calibration matrix is calculated as follows:

```
C =[f 0 px;
    0 f py;
    0 0 1];
```

First, I want to ask about the focal length `f` used in the camera calibration matrix. Should I use it with the value in pixels or mm? If in mm how can I get it?

Second I don't really know what the `px` and `py` variables stand for I got some information about the data I'm working on bye the `exifread` function in MATLAB and these are the information I got:

```
              Sharpness: 0
               Contrast: 0
       SceneCaptureType: 0
  FocalLengthIn35mmFilm: 27
       DigitalZoomRatio: 1
           WhiteBalance: 0
           ExposureMode: 0
              SceneType: 1
             FileSource: 3
          SensingMethod: 2
        PixelYDimension: 3000
        PixelXDimension: 4000
             ColorSpace: 1
        FlashpixVersion: '0100'
            FocalLength: 4.9000
                  Flash: 1
            LightSource: 0
           MeteringMode: 4
       MaxApertureValue: 3.6150
      ExposureBiasValue: 0
          ApertureValue: 3.6150
      ShutterSpeedValue: 2.3220
 CompressedBitsPerPixel: 2.8149
ComponentsConfiguration: [1 2 3 0]
      DateTimeDigitized: '2011:06:26 16:55:08'
       DateTimeOriginal: '2011:06:26 16:55:08'
            ExifVersion: '0221'
        ISOSpeedRatings: 100
        ExposureProgram: 2
                FNumber: 3.5000
           ExposureTime: 0.2000
              Copyright: 'Copyright 2010'
       YCbCrPositioning: 2
               DateTime: '2011:06:26 16:55:08'
               Software: '  0.8913'
         ResolutionUnit: 2
            YResolution: 96
            XResolution: 96
            Orientation: 1
                  Model: 'SAMSUNG ES30/VLUU ES30'
                   Make: 'SAMSUNG'
              Thumbnail: [1x1 struct]
```

Do `px` and `py` refer to any of them?

Answer (score 2):

px and py are the coordinates of the principal point. On an ideal camera that would be the center of the image, so you can use width/2, height/2 for a start. For actual values you should use a calibration algorithm.

f should be in pixels.